# Palindromic numbers in two bases, Project Euler #36

Tags: python

Here is my solution for [Project Euler problem 36](https://projecteuler.net/problem=36), which reads:

> The decimal number, 585 = 1001001001₂ (binary), is palindromic in both bases.
>
> Find the sum of all numbers, less than one million, which are palindromic in base 10 and base 2.
>
> (Please note that the palindromic number, in either base, may not include leading zeros.)

My result is somehow wrong. Could anyone help?

```
def findnum(n):
    a = 0
    for i in range(0, n + 1):
        temp = '{0:08b}'.format(i)
        if str(i) == str(i)[::-1] and str(temp) == str(temp)[::-1]:
            a += i 
    return a 

print findnum(1000000)
```

The result I got is 872096, but the correct answer seems to be 872187. But the difference of these two, 91, is not a palindrome. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is Problem 36 in Project Euler? Can you give us a problem statement?

Comment: Please add a quote of the problem in the question!

Comment: Added link to Euler #36 in question

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I see you have 14k rep, which is plenty to edit in whatever information you feel should be there.

Comment: In this case you are undoubtedly correct, just don't want any first poster to think that all questions get automatically amended.

Comment: @Oz123: we just [burninated the PE tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler); it is a meta tag. Please don't re-create it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You missed something in the problem description:

> Please note that the palindromic number, in either base, **may not include leading zeros**.

Yet you are using leading zeros:

```
temp = '{0:08b}'.format(i)
```

Drop the `08` from the format; there is no need to pad it to a width at all here:

```
temp = '{0:b}'.format(i)
```

With this change you'll get the correct answer.

You may as well just use the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) instead, as you are not putting the string into a larger template. You don't need to feed it to `str()` as `format()` already produces a string. I'd swap the tests to test for a binary palindrome first and avoid extra `str()` calls. The `n + 1` in the `range()` call is not needed; the problem description asks for all such numbers *below* 1 million:

```
for i in range(n):
    temp = format(i, 'b')
    if temp == temp[::-1] and str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
        a += i
```

or you could first test for the decimal palindrome, *then* format:

```
for i in range(n):
    decimal = str(i)
    if decimal != decimal[::-1]:
        continue
    binary = format(i, 'b')
    if binary == binary[::-1]:
        a += i
```

This shaves off quite a few calls from the overall runtime, making the final version more than twice as fast:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> def findnum_orig(n):
...     a = 0
...     for i in range(0, n + 1):
...         temp = '{0:b}'.format(i)
...         if str(i) == str(i)[::-1] and str(temp) == str(temp)[::-1]:
...             a += i 
...     return a 
... 
>>> def findnum_optimised(n):
...     a = 0
...     for i in range(n):
...         decimal = str(i)
...         if decimal != decimal[::-1]:
...             continue
...         binary = format(i, 'b')
...         if binary == binary[::-1]:
...             a += i
...     return a
... 
>>> timeit('fn(1000000)', 'from __main__ import findnum_orig as fn', number=10)
10.886759996414185
>>> timeit('fn(1000000)', 'from __main__ import findnum_optimised as fn', number=10)
3.7782959938049316
```

That's because `str()` is a lot faster than `format()`:

```
>>> timeit('for i in range(1000): str(i)', number=1000)
0.17951107025146484
>>> timeit('for i in range(1000): format(i, 'b')', number=1000)
0.2837510108947754
```

As there are only 1999 decimal and 2000 binary palindromes below 1 million:

```
>>> sum(1 for i in range(1000000) if str(i) == str(i)[::-1])
1999
>>> sum(1 for i in range(1000000) if format(i, 'b') == format(i, 'b')[::-1])
2000
```

avoiding the slower operation all but those 1999 decimal palindromes saves you a lot of time.

We can make it faster still by switching how you convert the integer to binary; the [`bin()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) produces a binary number too, albeit with the `0b` prefix. Even with having to remove that prefix using that function is faster than using `format()`:

```
>>> timeit('for i in range(1000): format(i, "b")', number=1000)
0.46987009048461914
>>> timeit('for i in range(1000): bin(i)[2:]', number=1000)
0.24124693870544434
```

and if you are using Python 2.x, you should also use the [`xrange()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) to avoid creating a list with 1.000.000 integers. This brings the final timings to:

```
>>> def findnum_bin_xrange(n):
...     a = 0
...     for i in xrange(n):
...         decimal = str(i)
...         if decimal != decimal[::-1]:
...             continue
...         binary = bin(i)[2:]
...         if binary == binary[::-1]:
...             a += i 
...     return a 
... 
>>> findnum_bin_xrange(1000000)
872187
>>> timeit('fn(1000000)', 'from __main__ import findnum_bin_xrange as fn', number=10)
3.5071611404418945
```

That's down to about 1/3rd of your original code timings.

Comment: just found out how 'accept my answer' worked...new to the community :)

Comment: also, no need to call `format` at all unless the number is palindromic in decimal.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: indeed; updated to avoid an extra `str()` call too by assigning that.

Comment: Or you could use `bin(i)[2:]` (Python 2.x).

Comment: @Aristide: I didn't think it'd be faster, but actually it is. `bin()` works on Python 3 too.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is roughly 20 times faster than Martijn's.

The approach is also slightly different, using the fact that the number has to read the same backwards. Instead of checking all numbers to see if they are a palindrome, I generate them myself. This introduces some extra lines of code since you have to treat 3 different cases:

- single digit (1,2,3 etc.),
- even digit (4334,5115 etc.),
- and uneven digit (121,87378 etc.) palindromes.

The main for-loop range can be reduced to 1000.

First all the Palindromic numbers (base10) are generated using the above strategy. The generated numbers are then checked in base2. If they are a palindromic number they are added to an array. (Further speed increase if you skip the array and just sum it in a variable.)

```
import time

#calculate digits
def digits(num):
    return len(str(num))
#reverse order
def reverse(num):
  return int(str(num)[::-1])

#check binary counterpartner
def bin_pal_chk(number):
    b = int(bin(number)[2:])
    if (b == reverse(b)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

#list with all base 10 palindromes
palin = []
#calculate palindromes
t = time.clock()
for i in range(1,1000):
    #single digits
    if (i < 10):
        if bin_pal_chk(i):
            palin.append(i)
    #even digits
    num = i*10**digits(i) + reverse(i)
    if bin_pal_chk(num):
        palin.append(num)
    #uneven digits
    if (i < 100):
        for j in range(10):
            num = i*10**(digits(i)+1) + j*10**digits(i) + reverse(i)
            if bin_pal_chk(num):
                palin.append(num)
print time.clock() - t
```

Comment: Doesn't matter that you can't post a comment... since you posted an answer(ish). When referring to other answers, you should be specific about which one, since the order they are shown can change. E.g., "Martijn's answer".